# Im trying to create a counter after clicking one of 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, dom-events

One of the buttons will roll the dice once. The other button will roll the dice 1000 times, every roll populates an array.prototype.map table

I want to record the total results that are being displayed after each button click (+1 and +1000)
this is what I have so far

```
document.getElementById("roll1") .document.addEventListener("click", counter())

function counter(){   
    numRolls+=1

}
function counter1000(){   
    numRolls+=1000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to pass in the reference to the `counter` function, not actually call it. Pass it without the braces.
2. `.document` doesn't exist on an HTML node (`#roll1`), use `addEventListener` without re-chaining `document`

```js
document.getElementById("roll1").addEventListener("click", counter)
document.getElementById("roll2").addEventListener("click", counter1000)

function counter(){   
    numRolls+=1

}
function counter1000(){   
    numRolls+=1000
}
```